# Return Work Item Details using VSTS with WIQL using JavaScript

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have the following function with which I want to return info about a work item, e.g. Completed Work. However, all I ever get in return as a list of work items are the ID and the URL.

I'd have thought specifying the fields I wanted within the SELECT statement would provide the answer but it seems to make no difference?

```
 function newGetWorkItems(queryType, iterationPath, projectId, listOfQueries)
   {
   var queryClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_QueryAPI.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);

   var query = "";

  if (queryType == 0) 

  {
    query = { query: "SELECT [System.Id],[System.CreatedBy] FROM WorkItems WHERE [System.IterationPath] = '" + iterationPath + "'" };

  }
```

As can see I'd have thought CreatedBy would be returned for each work item, but it's not, only for what I assume is the iteration I'm passing in .. ?

```
{"queryType":1,"queryResultType":1,"asOf":"2018-04-18T14:44:12.463Z",
"columns":[{"referenceName":"System.TeamProject","name":"Team Project","url":"http://xx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields"}],
"workItems":[{"id":34639,"url":"http://xx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/34639"},
```

Comment: Do you solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use directly the rest API from TFS?

I would suggest to make a POST with your query by wiql directly for the TFS API
URL: `https://<TFS URL>/tfs/<Collection>/<TeamProject>/_apis/wit/wiql`

You can find more information on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql

Another way to do that, you can create your own query, and then, request to be executed by rest API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/queries/get#query_by_name

Another way is, taking into consideration the answer of your request, you can iterate each result `"url":"http://xx:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/workItems/34639"` and get your answer.

Hope it helps,
Thank you

Comment: The reason I didn't want to use this method is because it requires authentication. The libraries I'm using (getWebContext) are specifically designed to assume the user is already logged in to the system. The problem I've got is since last week MS has moved the documentation and it is nowhere to be found - very irritating! As for the last suggestion, I didn't want to iterate through each as that would have meant a lot of seperate requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t get details of workitems through WIQL REST API, you need to get work item details with Ids through [Work Items – List REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/wit/work%20items/list). (**getWorkItems** function of Javascript SDK)

For example (per to your code):

```
 queryClient.getWorkItems([722,716]).then(function (wits) {
                    console.log(wits);
                });
```

Comment: Unfortunately the documentation for the JavaScript SDK has gone missing ... as of end of last week. Are you able to share the parameters that get passed into getWorkItems, e.g. does it accept iteration path?

Comment: @Journeyman1234 `getWorkItems(ids: number[], fields?: string[], asOf?: Date, expand?: WorkItemTrackingInterfaces.WorkItemExpand, errorPolicy?: WorkItemTrackingInterfaces.WorkItemErrorPolicy): Promise<WorkItemTrackingInterfaces.WorkItem[]>;` You can just specify workitems' id

Comment: You need to get workitems' id with your code, then call getWorkItems function.

Comment: I've already done the former, I use WIQL and pass in an iteration in order to get a list of work item IDs, which I can then parse into any format I need, so in your example below, would I put all the ones I'm interested in as so: ids: number[1,2,3,4,5] ?

Comment: Also, what class does getWorkItems belong to, pls? (WorkItemTrackingHttpClient? WorkHttpClient?)

Comment: `workItemTrackingClient`. I provided the sample code in the answer.